# TextInput stops taking input after one keystroke in react native text input - prohibiting continuous typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    defaultvalue={values.firstname}
    placeholder="Enter First Name"
    onChangeText={handleChange('firstname')}
    onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('firstname')}
/>
{(errors.firstname && touched.firstname) && (
    <Text style={styles.errors}>{errors.firstname}</Text>
)}
```

Whenever i try to write something it is taking one word and keyboard is getting disappeared

Comment: try removing the onChange and onBlur function. and errors. you need to simplify your question to make it easier to answer

Comment: Likely passing onChange turns the component into a "controlled" component which then requires you to explicitly pass in a value prop

Comment: it is happening due to scrollview 
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-virtualized-view';
any function of scroll view that i need to add